# Wrapping Apollo Client queries in facade layer

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am (very) new to Apollo client and graph ql in General

I started to write queries and use them with React js, and everything is working fine, but previously I used to add an additional layer when I want to make API calls (Like facade) for example:

I have getCountries method where its implementation returns a fixed shape of json, inside it I use whatever API calls, Axios, fetch or even getting static data from a file, no matter what the implementation is, or if I needed to change it, I am sure the getCountries function will return the same shape of object and I do not need to change anything in any other src files.

When I started to use Apollo, they mentioned that in their [website][1]

> Apollo Client really shines when it's integrated with a view layer
> like React. You can bind queries to your UI and update it
> automatically as new data is fetched.

So what I am doing is similar to their [tutorial repo][2] where they using it directly something similar:

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  useQuery(GET_CONUTRIES, {
    onCompleted: setCountries,
  });
```

or something like:

```
const {data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_COUNTRIES);
```

I mean I am using it with no wrapping, which gives me a feeling that I am not doing the best practice at all and I still need wrapping

Is there a best practice for using Apollo with React? I mean should we wrap it or?
[1]: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/
[2]: https://github.com/apollographql/fullstack-tutorial/blob/main/final/client/src/pages/cart.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using custom hooks can be as a wrapper for that